# 2 phase to 3 phase

Tags: phase

I received a heat tunnel from Asia that has 2 wires. The manual says, "It uses two phase 220V and tri-feet plug with one of it used for the safe wire connecting case and the ground." I have a 3 phase 220V outlet. What do you suggest?

Comment: An ordinary outlet with 3-phase current? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Use only one of your phases.  First actually measure your outlet's AC volts between prongs.

A 3-phase outlet will be ~208VAC on a single phase, for roughly 90% heating on a heater designed for 220VAC.

If ya jus' gotta have 240VAC etc., (certain scroll pumps cannot tolerate 208VAC,)  then add a boost transformer (got from Grainger or similar, either 12/24VAC or 16/32AVAC output, called "buck/boost transformers.")   These are just a high-amps single-phase step-down xfrmr with low volts output at tens of amperes.  Wire their output in series with the 208VAC, for many kilowatts at higher voltage.

MUCH higher output power results, when compared to a single 208/240V step up xfrmer where the entire energy-flow is heating the transformer-core.  With the "boost" voltage added to the 208VAC, the transformer-core only sees roughly 1/4 of the wattage sent to the load, so the boost transformer can be about 1/4 the size of a standard step-up transformer

The 12/24 version converts 208VAC to 220 or 232, while the 16/32 version gives you 224VAC or 240VAC.

PS

TMI, the true 3PH/2PH converter is the Westinghouse "Scott-T" transformer, to adapt the original 4-wire 90eg dynamos to 3-wire 120deg systems.  (These replaced the GE rotary converters, entire motor/generator pairs!)   It all dates from the "war of currents" era, where Edison/GE, having lost the battle to promote DC while ignoring the expanding AC-grid, suddenly pretended to have invented AC power lines, as if Nikola Tesla had only patented 2 to 30 phases, and somehow forgot 3-phase (he didn't.)

[Wikipedia: Scott-T transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott-T_transformer)

The first "polyphase" system used four coils and four linking wires, while the latecomers adopted six-coil devices connected by only three transmission lines.  In the nasty (and dishonest) patent-battle which resulted, the lawyers' fees threatened to destroy all companies involved, so J.P. Morgan strode in, fired Edison, and cut a licensing deal with Westinghouse Inc., where everyone made huge piles of money, and nobody ever admitted to losing the War of Currents.